# Upper RF limit in discrete design

Tags: circuit-analysis, rf, integrated-circuit, microwave

I was curious, what is viewed as the practical upper frequency limit of circuits using discrete components?

It's well known a 20Ghz oscillator is hard to design using discrete components due to the parasitics but very easy to design in an IC because such parasitics are dramatically smaller in magnitude.

So what is viewed as the practical upper frequency limit for discrete circuit design?

Comment: Define "discrete". You mean zero ICs?

Comment: Supposedly there are [Gunn diode oscillators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunn_diode#Gunn_diode_oscillators) up to 200 GHz.

Comment: @ DKNguyen yes zero IC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, solid state circuits are usable up to 300 GHz, although you'll find circuits that exceed that. It depends on the type of transistor used, e.g. BJTs vs HBTs vs MESFETs vs HEMTs (in roughly increasing order of frequency range if I recall correctly). That goes for integrated circuits in general. For discrete components (off the shelf, through-hole or SMT), a feasible upper end is 1-30 GHz, and you'd be hard-pressed to achieve that depending on the components sizes.

Discrete passives (resistors, inductors, capacitors) can be used all the way to 30 GHz and beyond without too much issue as long as the size decreases. You won't find dipped inductors packaged like resistors, for example, but bond-wire coils? Sure. The disconnect here is scale, where to get any sensible performance, the components need to be millimeter dimensions or smaller. Thats not what comes to mind as 'discrete' for many folks, but it counts.

Can you assemble such a circuit without automation? Yes, but it's not easy. It is far more economical to use integrated devices.

If you picture discretes as 0805 chip resistors and radial disk ceramic caps, normal copper traces on FR4 circuit board, hand soldered and built in a kit, you're thinking in the completely wrong headspace. Many SMD caps and resistors work fine at 30 GHz (if theyre designed for it), but the design itself has now changed to revolve around distributed elements (realized with microstrip, stripline, CPWG, etc) and the circuit board material now makes a dramatic difference, because electromagnetics are at play. Your passives may be realized now with stubs, or your resonators become quarterwave lengths of transmission line instead of LC tanks.

As for transistors and such, you have integrated devices which are obviously preferable, but packaged devices can be used maybe up to several 10s of GHz and beyond. These aren't TO packages, and theyre certainly not through-hole, theyre microwave transistors in microwave packaging. "Chip" devices (raw dies you connect bond wire to) are common above 10 GHz, mounted on a proper substrate (a 'laminate' is the term for a microwave PCB substrate).

This obviously requires having access to bonding machines and technicians that can use them, and there are myriad problems along with that in materials (conductive epoxy, laminates, plated microstrip or stripline elements), connections and homogeneity (mounting the die to make sufficient contact to avoid reflections and loss), connectors (they get real expensive real fast), test equipment (you'll need a good VNA like a PNA-X), and, of course, the technicians who can put in the time to assemble and verify everything.

To answer the question, as with all things in engineering: it depends. It depends on your definition of discrete, on how much work and money you're willing to put in, on what type of performance is satisfactory. Often, it's not a question of "can you" but "should you", as the discrete solution will quickly become extremely expensive. An LC filter realized with discrete components at 12 GHz? Expensive. A microstrip realization, e.g. commensurate line filter or coupled line filter or hairpin filter? You can do that at home, if you understand the theory and the design tools. An oscillator? You can do it on a MMIC or using a discrete transistor and a microstrip resonator and supporting circuitry, and the frequency limit goes to the 10s of GHz with proper construction. As the frequency increases, more specialized devices become common, like Gunn diodes, YIG oscillators, etc. So you wouldn't use discretes as they exist in low frequency design, for any good reason anyway.

Edit:

After reading the OPs response to another answer: if you're interested in building a 20 GHz oscillator on the bench without expensive tools, then that should be its own question. If you just want something to play with, performance be damned, don't ask about if it's possible with discretes, but rather ask how to obtain that specific goal without spending a huge amount of money. Discrete is not the same as simple or cheap; in fact at 20 GHz it is quite the opposite. Working at those high frequencies requires a large investment. $10,000 might get you started with an RF sig gen, a basic spectrum analyzer, an older network analyzer, and the requisite supply of connectors, cables, and devices to make development possible. That is, if you buy instruments "as-is" and repair them, which is the cheapest way to get good instrumentation, though it's always a risk depending on your experience. If youre more experienced you could develop more of your own instrumentation, but asking this question in the first place suggests that thats not in the cards.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Do you feel discrete circuit design has a place in the upper frequency bands or should everything be done in an IC? Basically I was curious how much anyone cares about discrete circuit design anymore, particularly in high-speed circuits.

Comment: To call something "discrete circuit design" is a bit misleading, because it's not clear what that entails. Electronics can't necessarily be broken into "discrete" and "integrated", it's something of a spectrum, especially at high frequencies. The design principles would be the same whether you use MMICs or discrete elements, and often they are used together to suit a particular application. I guess you could say, there's no such thing as "discrete circuit design", only "circuit design." The design aspects that are important won't change whether a circuit is discrete or not.

Comment: Ok let me reformulate - do you feel design using discrete active components which don't involve wire-bonding machines still has a place in higher frequencies?  As in not fabing a custom IC.

Comment: Oh I think I see what you're asking. Yes, and really, wire bonding to dies (or rather 'dice') is still an off-the-shelf discrete solution, it just requires extra equipment. But see e.g. here: http://www.mwtinc.com/products/gaas-mesfet-chips/ for an example of discrete transistors that are usable up to at least 12 GHz. These types of transistors are probably as common as chips (raw dice). Microwave boards are definitely still manufactured using discrete transistors like this. It depends on how cost effective it is when taken with the rest of the design, but it's common

Comment: You can see some examples by searching around for microwave amplifiers, like e.g. https://images.app.goo.gl/GoedzbiAYbJ8s3Zh8u . A product that needs to be tunable or configurable with smaller scale production would probably go for a discrete solution, while a large scale production device like a cell phone would aim for as high a level of integration as possible, so the design will be much more "connect the black boxes" but that's what you want when manufacturing large numbers of identical devices

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the "RF stuff" is the limit.

How about 32/33 prescalars, certainly an untuned circuit?

You can build frequency-multipliers (X2, X3) as needed to reach higher frequencies, but can you get power gain?

As long as you have some non-linearity, you've got a mixer for UP or for Down conversion.

I've built S-band (1.2GHz) oscillators on my workbench, on Rogers Duroid, with about 2" stripline hanging on the emitter of a micro_T transistors.

If you want a quality oscillator, you mount the active device atop the resonator (stripline or cavity or ceramic ball)

========================

Motorola had micro_T transistors with 4+GHz Ftau, the ceramic body being 3mm across, 40+ years ago. Who knows what they could provide for SPECIAL CUSTOMERS?

For 30GHz resonance in air dielectric (so we know the precise size needed), the wavelength is 1cm; quarter-wave is 2.5mm. Is a cavity better?

Thus working with **BARE DIE** may be needed. Not sure BareDie count as Discrete.

If you can bond the Emitter to a Resonator quarter_wave, with a varactor die bonded to the other end for tuning, we may have something.

I would think the Electronic Warfare people have long pushed the frontiers of what is possible, in building monitoring equipment that supports AVOID SURPRISES.

Comment: But can you design a 20ghz oscillator with a discrete transistor?